# BLE service UUID--System.FormatException: 'Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).'

Tags: c#, uwp, uuid, formatexception

I am writing a UWP code to connect with nearby BLE devices.
In this line of code...

```
GattDeviceServicesResult result = await GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(
    new System.Guid("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),
    BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached
);
```

...it is giving me the error...

> System.FormatException: 'Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).'

I have double checked the characterstic UUID  is 1809 and I have converted it to 128 bit UUID but still it gives error.

Comment: From where is the exception being thrown?  `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync()`?  `new System.Guid("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")` executes fine for me.

Comment: To @BACON's point - https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bQhOx

Comment: I am running a UWP app from "BluetoothLE" example from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples.

Comment: I am running it on Visual Studio 2017 and when I run the code it gives me my above mentioned  error

Comment: I am using using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile; namespace in the code with GetGattServicesForUuidAsync method. At this point exception is being thrown

Comment: Your code snippet are not enough to reproduce your issue. [GetGattServicesForUuidAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.getgattservicesforuuidasync) method is not just invoking as you showed. Please provide more details.